# Where can i find the deploy log in python app deployed in Openshift

Tags: python, django, logging, openshift

I wanna be able to find the output text of the "deploy" script, that openshift calls automatically.

Suppose I have the following line in that "deploy" script:

python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"wsgi/openshift/manage.py syncdb --noinput

Then I wanna see the output text of that call...

I already looked at the openshifthome/python/logs, and there are access* and error* logs, but there are no the ouputs that I want.

I want this because some times, after I push to the master git branch, it fails, and I wanna know where it fails...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deploy output is logged to stdout if I recall correctly. If you git push from the command line you should see where things are failing.